# gparted unmet dependencies error while installing

Tags: ubuntu

trying to install gparted but gives unmet dependencies error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get -f install
```

If that doesn't work, just install it through the app center. Or the tedious way is it lists exactly what you are missing, so you could install each dependency.

Comment: i tried many times, even tried to install through app center, can you help me thru team viewer

Comment: Did you try installing the individual dependencies?

Comment: yes i did some installed, but 2 of them again are giving the error, do you have team viewer please help

Comment: sorry I don't have team viewer. What error are you getting?

Comment: This might satisfy your needs...http://gparted.org/livecd.php